# Change of basis from basis $B$ to $F$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Tags: vector-spaces, change-of-basis

I have never worked with vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$. I have the basis

> $B=\{e_4=(2,1,0,7), e_5=(-1,2,-2,-5), e_6=(1,-1,5,12)\}$

and

> $F=\{e_1=(1,0,-1,1), e_2=(0,1,-1,-1), e_3=(0,0,1,2)\}$

Is the subspace spanned by $B$ the same as $F$? If affirmative, give the change of basis matrix from this basis $B$ to the original basis defined by the vectors $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$.

I think first of all, I have to do this step: $Pb \to F = [[e_4]_F, [e_5]_F, [e_6]_F]$

Can someone either give me a hint, or preferably guide me towards an example of this type of problem?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. Please use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to format posts.

Comment: By the way, I get what you mean by "Is $B$ a basis of $F$?", but technically you should ask whether $B$ is a basis for $\mathrm{span}(F)$, or whether they span the same subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, or something else equivalent. I've submitted an edit for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint on the general method for solving this kind of problem, I've left the details to you as you've requested.

First show that $B$ and $F$ are both linearly independent, i.e. if

$$\lambda_1 e_1 + \lambda_2 e_2 + \lambda_3 e_3 = 0$$

then $\lambda_1$ = $\lambda_2$ = $\lambda_3=0$. Similarly for $e_4$, $e_5$, $e_6$.

This tells us that the dimensions of the subspaces of $B$ and $F$ are both $3$.

To show that $\mathrm{span}(B)=\mathrm{span}(F)$, then, we need to show that any vector in $B$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis elements of $F$. In fact, it is sufficient to do that for the basis elements of $B$, since all vectors in $B$ will be a linear combination of the basis elements.

This then specifies the change of basis matrix. Take the basis elements of $B$, and write them as a linear combination of the basis elements of $F$, this then specifies the columns of the matrix $P$ - as you noted, $P = [[e_4]_F, [e_5]_F, [e_6]_F]$.

Comment: Change of Basis matrix P is coming this n ;  P = [(1, 0, -1, 1), (0, 1, -1, -1), (0, 0, 1, 3)] Am I correct?

Comment: @DarshitSharma The change of basis matrix should be $3 \times 3$, since we are mapping from a subspace with dimension $3$ to a subspace with dimension $3$. In the basis of $F$, $(1, 0, -1, 1)$ becomes $(1, 0, 0)$, and so on.

Comment: @DarshitSharma I don't get it. How would you solve the problem?

Comment: @ManuelYerbes The vector $e_4$ will be expressible as some $\lambda_1 e_1 + \lambda_2 e_2 + \lambda_3 e_3$, that is, the first column of the matrix $P$ is $[e_4]_F=(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)^T$. Similarly for the other columns.

Comment: Ok, I get it. All I have to do is: 

x{e1} + y{e2} +z{e3} = {e4};

x{e1} + y{e2} +z{e3} = {e5};

x{e1} + y{e2} +z{e3} = {w6};

Comment: @ManuelYerbes Yep, exactly! Then, those $x$, $y$, $z$ specify the columns. More generally, a matrix’s columns can be read as where it sends basis vectors.